# What is w in chi-square effect size power calculation in R?

Tags: r, chi-squared

I am attempting to do a power calculation in R for a chi-square test of association. I know the size of each group and the power and alpha I need, and I want to know how large of difference in proportion I can detect between the two groups. I found the "pwr" package in R, but I am confused about the meaning of w, the effect size. Is this value Cramer's V? How is it calculated? How can it be converted into a difference in proportion between the two groups?

Comment: No, it's not Cramèr's V, it's [Cohen's w](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effect_size#Cohen's_w). At an R prompt, run `pwr::ES.w1` to see the source code, it's the formula in that Wikipedia link.

Comment: To be an acceptable question on SO it needs to have code and data as a starting point and then further coding will be able to deliver a coding "answer". Your question doesn't appear to have either code or data.